# how to get a list for unique pandas dataframe column elements?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get a list for each unique string in a pandas dataframe column:

```
import pandas as pd

catalog = {'code': ['A001', 'A001', 'A001', 'A002', 'A002'], 'title': ['director', 'president', 'vice president', 'sales director', 'sales vice president']}

catalog=pd.DataFrame(catalog)

## unique column values ##
codes = catalog['code'].unique()

for code in codes:
     titles = catalog[catalog == code]['title'].tolist()
     print(titles)
```

Which gives the next output:

```
[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
```

Expected output could look like this:

```
['director', 'president', 'vice president']
['sales director', 'sales vice president']
```

What am I missing?
Is there any other way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want a list of _all_ values for each _unique_ value in `code`, right? So if you had two rows with `director` within code `A001`, the resulting list would have `director` twice?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has an issue where you compare the full dataframe when assigning the `title` variable , instead of comparing with a column:

```
for code in codes:
    titles = catalog[catalog['code'] == code]['title'].tolist()
    print(titles)
```

Or:

```
for code in codes:
    titles = catalog.loc[catalog['code'] == code,'title'].tolist()
    print(titles)
```

---

```
['director', 'president', 'vice president']
['sales director', 'sales vice president']
```

Answer (score 4):

Try with

```
catalog.groupby('code')['title'].unique()
code
A001     [director, president, vice president]
A002    [sales director, sales vice president]
Name: title, dtype: object
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but based on OP's attempt, it looks like they want a list of all values for each `code`, not just unique values from each `code`

Comment: @sacuL the question title confused ~

Answer (score 3):

Instead of iterating through the unique codes, it's easier to use a groupby:

```
catalog.groupby("code").title.apply(list)

code
A001    [director, president, vice president]
A002    [sales director, sales vice president]
Name: title, dtype: object
```